# Installing ruby-debug-base19 on Windows in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: windows, ruby-debug, ruby-1.9.3

I need to install ruby-debug-base19 in order to active debug on Netbeans IDE, when I execute:

```
$ gem install ruby-debug-base19
```

I got the following error. Extracted from log generate

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for rb_method_entry_t.body in method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
generating ruby_debug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:24:19: error: conflicting types for 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option'
C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p125/vm_core.h:505:7: note: previous declaration of 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option' was here
ruby_debug.c: In function 'context_jump':
ruby_debug.c:2378:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
ruby_debug.c:2392:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1
```

**Prerequisites:**

Ruby installed successfully

```
$ ruby --version
>>ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

DevKit installed successfully

```
$ gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
>>Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>>Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>>Successfully installed rdiscount-1.6.8
>>1 gem installed
>>Installing ri documentation for rdiscount-1.6.8...
>>Installing RDoc documentation for rdiscount-1.6.8...

$ ruby -rubygems -e "require 'rdiscount'; puts RDiscount.new('**Hello RubyInstaller**').to_html"
>><p><strong>Hello RubyInstaller</strong></p>
```

I have read [this article](http://webdevwonders.com/install-ruby-debug19-on-windows/) without success.

What I'm missing?

Comment: I can't stand with this error. I use ```gem debugger``` instead!

Answer (score 9):

1) download linecache19-0.5.13.gem and ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=8883

2) gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem

3) gem install ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=c:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1\ruby-1.9.3-p125

Comment: The above steps worked for me, but before that I had to isntall other gems as listed here on page 6

http://csc.columbusstate.edu/woolbright/class/wkenna.pdf