# I can't install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.25 on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-debug

I'm trying to install Rails on Windows 7.

When I install I get this error:

```
make
generating ruby_debug-i386-mingw32.def
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:29:19: error: conflicting types for 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option'
C:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby-1.9.3-p194/vm_core.h:505:7: note: previous declaration of 'rb_iseq_compile_with_option' was here
ruby_debug.c: In function 'context_jump':
ruby_debug.c:2414:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
ruby_debug.c:2428:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.25/ext/ruby_debug/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.25'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I installed ruby-debug-base19 -v '0.11.26 following "[Installing ruby-debug-base19 on Windows in Ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705947/installing-ruby-debug-base19-on-windows-in-ruby-1-9-3)"

Comment: Have you tried installing latest (0.11.25) instead?

Comment: @LuisLavena i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just comment it out in the gemfile

```
#  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

You can try better_errors for debugging if you like [Link to better_errors](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)